# SELECT SUBSTRING(column) ... HAVING SUBSTRING(column) cause unknown column error in mysql

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, ..)
FROM someTable
GROUP BY SUBSTSRING(column, ..)
HAVING SUBSTRING(column, ..) IS NULL;
```

The query written above resulted in an error. But,

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, ..) AS otherName
FROM someTable
GROUP BY SUBSTSRING(column, ..)
HAVING otherName IS NULL;
```

The query written above is OK. What causes this result?

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: @AliFidanli ERROR 1054 at line 1: Unknown column 'column' in 'having clause' :(

Comment: An expression in HAVING in 1st query refers to `column` column name which is not available after grouping. Use `GROUP BY SUBSTSRING(column, ..), column`.

Answer (score 0):

Read mysql doc [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#:%7E:text=The%20SQL%20standard%20requires%20that,in%20outer%20subqueries%20as%20well.)

---

from doc: The SQL standard requires that HAVING **must reference only columns** in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However, MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as well.